# I can't fetch string to display with each char

Tags: java, string

why did I can't do this, How can I do like CPP?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
     String n = "ABCDEFG";
     for(int i=0;i<n.length();i++){
           System.out.println(n[i]);
     }
 }
```

When I complier it said "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String".

Comment: `char[] chars = n.toCharArray();`

Comment: @Shivam Kalra. Do not convert to array of `chars` if you don't have to.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak why not? He could simple iterate over using character array using indexing.

Comment: @Shivam Karla. Because you double a memory footprint, when you convert String to char array.  Simple is often, but not always efficient.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak You win!

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [`charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) function to access characters of a `String`. As MrSmith42 mentions, overloading of the `[]` operator is possible in C++'s `std::string`, but not with Javas `String`

```
System.out.println(n.charAt(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `String` is not an array.

You can, however, convert it to a `char` array and cycle over it using a foreach loop like this:

```
for (char c: n.toCharArray())
    System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: Undid -1, seems to harsh.  It's good to mention a possibility of converting String to char array, however for OP's problem this seem to be an overkill.

Comment: @Alexander Pogrebnyak: It might be a little 'overkill' but it also might be faster than calling `charAt(..)` for each charaxter in the String

Comment: @MrSmith42. If you think iterator is doing something different, but on a COPY of the array, you would be disappointed.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak I guess I am too used to working with `CharBuffer`s :p

Answer (score 2):

Java does not allow operator overloading, like c++ does. Therefore the []-operator cannot be used on Strings.

```
    System.out.println(n.charAt(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` objects do not support operator overloading like in C++. You could use

```
System.out.println(n.charAt(i));
```